# If I pass JNI a negative infinity (or NaN, or...) from C++ code, is it guaranteed to be negative infinity in Java?

Tags: java, c++, java-native-interface

Let's say I have a GUI in Java which calls some C++ code via JNI.

Java has hard-defined values for negative-infinity, NaN, etc. for Float and Double (e.g. see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Float.html#NEGATIVE_INFINITY).  On C++ this can depend on the platform, and we can access the actual value using std::numeric_limits.

Now let's say the following pseudo-code were jni calls:

```
float NIFloat { return -std::numeric_limits<float>::infinity();}
double NIDouble { return -std::numeric_limits<double>::infinity();}
```

Would this code work on multiple platforms?  I.e., in Java would the following evaluate to true:

```
Float.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == NIFloat();
Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY == NIDouble();
```

What would happen in the following case:

```
double NILongD {-std::numeric_limits<long double>::infinity();}
```

Would this be translated to Java's `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY`?

If this is not cross platform, is there a cross-platform safe way to communicate such values across JNI?

Comment: That's not so clear; it mainly depends on the libc embedded in the JVM running the java application. Your C++ compiler also has a role in this question.

If possible, try to pass bitwise values via JNI and (re)constructing your Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY from those bits in Java.

Comment: I'd think that if you need to be certain no matter what the platform, you need to extract the Java value from the proper Java class.  For example, pull `Double.NEGATIVE_INFINITY` by calling `GetStaticDoubleField` on the `Double` class.

Comment: Besides the fact that the “platform dependent” floating point values usually adhere to the same IEEE standard as Java’s floating point values, what would be the point of a JNI implementation that doesn’t convert between native values and Java values correctly? That’s the primary purpose of the interface…

Comment: @Holger: I completely agree with you.  It seems like a reasonable assumption to me, but I'm maintaining code where a different assumption was made, and I'm wondering if I can safely argue the point.

Comment: It seems, the specification takes this so much for granted that they didn’t even consider mentioning it. We also assume that double values like `1.0` are guaranteed to reach the other side without any doubt…